# validate chained select

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form like this:-

```
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="subjectList1">
      <select name="language[]" class="required" id="f61">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Malay</option>
        <option>Mandarin</option>
        <option>Tamil</option>
        <option>Arabic</option>
      </select>
    </div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><select name="spoken[]" class="required">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
      <option value="Spoken">Spoken</option>
      <option value="Written">Written</option>
      <option value="Spoken and written">Spoken and written</option>
    </select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><select name="fluency[]" class="required">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
      <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
      <option value="Average">Average</option>
      <option value="Fluent">Fluent</option>
      <option value="Mother tongue">Mother tongue</option>
    </select></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="other" id="showOther1" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Others</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div id="otherLanguegeReq1"><input type="text" id="language1" style="display:none;" class="required" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <br />
```

can I validate the dropdown-"spoken[]" & dropdown-"fluency[]" when the language[]'s value is not empty?

any idea on this?

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly call something like the below onsubmit or when you want to validate it. Within the each function you could build out a message or .addClass("incomplete") to visually style required elements as well.

```
function ValidateInputs() {
  var complete = true;
  if($("#f61 option:selected") != ""){

    $(".required").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        complete = false;
      }
    });

    if (!complete) {
      alert("Please ensure that you have completed all required fields.");
    }

  }
  return complete;
}
```